# Is there any function in this way?

Tags: real-analysis

$f$ is a function which is continous on $\Bbb R$, and $f^2$ is differentiable at $x=0$. Suppose $f(0)=1$. Must $f$ be differentiable at $0$?

I may feel it is not necessarily for $f$ to be differentiable at $x=0$ though $f^2$ is. But I cannot find a counterexample to disprove this. Anyone has an example?

Comment: One note: some people may thing $\,f^2\,$ means the composition of $\,f\,$ with itself, whereas *I think* you actually meant the function squared...If I'm correct, then perhaps it'd be better to denote that as $\,f(x)^2\,$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Differentiability of $f$ is existence of $\lim(f(x)-1)/x$. Differentiability of $f^2$ is existence of $\lim((f(x))^2-1)/x$. Consider factoring the numerator of the latter and thinking about the consequences.

Comment: SO the conclusion will be f must be differentiable at 0 if f^2 is differentiable at 0?

Comment: Sure looks that way.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\frac{f(x)-1}{x}=\frac{f(x)^2-1}{x}\frac{1}{f(x)+1}\xrightarrow [x\to 0]{}...?$$

Comment: So... the conclusion will be f must be differentiable at 0?

Comment: Well...does the limit hinted at above exist finitely? I'd say it does...